# Python Extract text in middle of string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, extract

I would like to extract the name of the item from the text.

```
fg['Product'] = pd.Series([' 5 Guys Greasy Burger 3/5LB (24) [51656]', '5 Guys Super Strawberry Shake - (3/4) OZ (9) [5645654], '5 Guys Giant Loaded Double Cheese Burger 1/2LB Buns - 8Z Cups (22) [564654]'])
```

What I need in the df column for analysis by product

```
fg['Product'] = 'Greasy Burger', 'Super Strawberry Shake', 'Giant Loaded Double Cheese Burger'
```

I have tried multiple things, but this got me the closest.

```
fg['Product'] = fg['Product'].str.strip('5 Guys').str.replace(r'\[d+\]')
```

But this isn't close to getting me there. The logic in the pattern appears to be strip '5 Guys' and then remove anything after the first numeric digit or the first hyphen '-'. Just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the regex `r"5 Guys ([A-Za-z\s]*)"` to every entry, which selects the group after `r"5 Guys "` containing all alphabetical characters and spaces. Maybe you have to find a more sophisticated pattern if there are also names with a number in it. I used an online regex helper for easier pattern creation (e.g. [regex101](https://regex101.com/)).

Full code example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

regex_pattern = r"5 Guys ([A-Za-z\s]*)"

def find_name(full_string):
    match = re.search(regex_pattern, full_string)
    print(match[1])

s = pd.Series([' 5 Guys Greasy Burger 3/5LB (24) [51656]', '5 Guys Super Strawberry Shake - (3/4) OZ (9) [5645654]', '5 Guys Giant Loaded Double Cheese Burger 1/2LB Buns - 8Z Cups (22) [564654]'])
s.apply(lambda x: find_name(x))
```

Comment: Thank you, so much. I had tried some combination of A-Za-z, but added [0-9]. Definitely need to read up on regex.

Comment: Happy to help, using regex helpers makes this stuff a lot easier. Please mark the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Marked. Hopefully, I get better at Python so I can start helping people

Comment: Chris, what if 5 guys is not just 5 guys but now includes: 1324, 1324 cups, or Big Lots, also as leading exclusions?

Comment: In regex you can use the "|" character to allow for multiple options in a group, e.g. `(5 Guys|abc|cef) ([A-Za-z\s]*)`. You then have to select the second match in the group, as every () marks a matching group. I recommend you to follow an introduction to regex, e.g. https://regexone.com/

Comment: I had tried |, but to no avail (User error, obviously). Thank you for the link. I will look at it today.

Answer (score 0):

```
r"5 Guys (.*?)(?=[0-9]|-)"
```

Details:

- `(.*?)`: Group1 - any character as few as possible
- `(?=[0-9]|-)`: Conditon (when we meet first numeric digit or the first hyphen) to stop regex

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4J1T0u/2)

Comment: Thank you, Than. This logic will really help me going forward

Comment: @chasedcribbet. You are welcome. If my answer is useful, please check mark on the left of answer.